# Matplotlib froze when updating scatter plot on top of an image in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a image of map and a number (20k) of [x, y]s from a trajectory. I would like to iterate through each one of the location pair sequentially and plot them onto the map.

```
floorplan = plt.imread("Floor-Plan.jpeg")
for index, row in tqdm(raw_data.iterrows()):
    location = NavigationFunction(row)
    plt.imshow(floorplan)
    plt.scatter(location[0], location[1], s=10)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This code works for a few iterations and then stops updating.

I also tried taking plt.imshow() line out of the for loop, and it only plots the first line of the for loop. Using ax.scatter and set data to scatter doesnt work neither.

I am suspecting that the floorplan is loaded each time plot updates and it slows down the process. Can I set the floorplan as background so that I only need to load the floorplan once? Or is there any other way so that I can update the plot at a high frequency with getting stuck? Thanks.

Comment: I guess its because you call `plt.imshow` in each iteration... Since you need to plot the background only once, you should put it outside the loop!

Comment: @raphael yes i have tried that and the plot was not updating at all.

Comment: its a bit hard to tell what your script does if there's a part that's called `somefunction()` right before the problematic part...  If you change your code into to a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can try to help

Comment: @raphael Thanks so much for trying to help. The "somefunction()" is just a navigation algorithm that takes in the "row" data and outputs location. The problem is resolved when I change the sleep duration to a larger value e.g. 2. I guess its just that the algorithm and floorplan loading takes some time to compute and it froze eventually.

Comment: ok... then it comes back to the fact that I'm still a bit unsure what you ultimately try to achieve whith this loop... do you want to render an animation? (or in other words... why do you need to plot the locations one by one and not all at once? (which would be a zillion times faster) why do you need to call `plt.show()` and `time.sleep(0.1)` in each iteration step?)

Comment: @raphael yes you are correct I wanted to plot the locations one by one so I can see how it changes over time. Animation is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: OK, if animation is your goal then I suggest you have a look at [blitting](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html) which would solve all our performance issues by drawing the background only once and caching it. It requires you to dig a bit deeper into matplotlib but it will most certainly pay off for the task you're trying to achieve.